# adding context QMenu to left click on a button in PySide

Tags: contextmenu, pyside, qmenu

I want to add context menu to **left click** of mouse button pressed over `emailbtn`

```
from PySide import QtCore,QtGui
import sys
class ToolBarUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ToolBarUI,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.createActions()

        self.floatingToolBar()
        pass

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(65,45)

    def buttons(self):
        x,y=15,35
        self.btnVLay=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.btnVLay)
        self.btnVLay.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.incSavbtn=QtGui.QPushButton("Save")
        self.incSavbtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(x,y))
        self.emailbtn=QtGui.QPushButton("Email")
        self.emailbtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(x,y))
        self.upldbtn=QtGui.QPushButton("Upload")
        self.upldbtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(x,y))
        self.setPrjbtn=QtGui.QPushButton("Set Project")
        self.setPrjbtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(x,y))
        self.setThumb=QtGui.QPushButton("Set thumb")
        self.setThumb.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(x,y))
        self.shwMatbtn=QtGui.QPushButton("Show Material")
        self.shwMatbtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(x,y))
        self.fixtexbtn=QtGui.QPushButton("Fix Texture Paths")
        self.fixtexbtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(x,y))

        btns = [self.incSavbtn,self.emailbtn,self.upldbtn,self.setPrjbtn,self.setPrjbtn,self.setThumb,self.shwMatbtn,self.fixtexbtn]

        [self.btnVLay.addWidget(each) for each in btns]

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction(self.emlSel)
        menu.addAction(self.emlScn)
        menu.addAction(self.emlBufr)
        #menu.exec_(self.emailbtn.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0,0)))
        #menu.exec_(event.globalPos())

    def createActions(self):

        self.emlSel = QtGui.QAction("Email Selected", self)

        self.emlScn = QtGui.QAction("Email this Scene", self)

        self.emlBufr = QtGui.QAction("Email Current Frame Buffer", self)


    def floatingToolBar(self):
        self.buttons()
        self.setLayout(self.btnVLay)
        self.show()
        pass

if __name__ =='__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = ToolBarUI()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried in `contextMenuEvent` method but that gives me on right click :/
What am i missing ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could use the [`setMenu`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpushbutton.html#setMenu) method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.actionHello = QtGui.QAction(self)
        self.actionHello.setText("Hello")

        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionHello)

        self.buttonShow = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonShow.setText("Button with menu")
        self.buttonShow.setMenu(self.menu)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonShow)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

    main = myWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I guess you mean *right* click? Please be more explicit, I don't seem to understand where your issue is

Comment: @XJacobs: no left click on button , as I mentioned in the first line of this post: and that to on `emailbtn`

Comment: well, the context menu in my example pops up on left click.

Comment: @san I suppose you ran my example as it is, just replacing `PyQt4` with `PySide`?

Answer (score 4):

It works in Linux but not in windows.

Below is code I used for systemtrayicon with left click support in windows. This might work for you as well.

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)"), self.iconActivated)   

def iconActivated(self, reason):

    if reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger: // left click, right click is Context
        self.contextMenu().activateWindow() // menu will disappear on clicking any where other than menu
        self.contextMenu().popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos()) // display menu at cursor location
```

Comment: .activateWindow() did the trick.  Took all day to find this fix to making the left click menu "go away" when I click elsewhere.  Thanks a bunch!